# javascript navigator.geolocation.watchPosition() doesn't work on android firefox

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, leaflet, geolocation

I am working on a Leaflet web app that watches hikers position on a map.
My code works on all android browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera, DuckDuckGo, Brave, and so on)
but fails with Mozilla Firefox.
Firefox just shows the initial position, but then remains stuck on that first position
without showing you further positions when you move.
Then after a minute, the 'timeout' error appears.
Here is my code:

```
if(!navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("Your browser doesn't support geolocation feature!")
         } else {
        tracciamento = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(getPosition, error, {maximumAge:600000, timeout:60000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
        }

function error(error){
            switch(error.code){
                case 1:
                    alert('geolocation is not enabled');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    alert('position not available');
                    break;
                case 3:
                    alert('timeout');
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('unknown error');
                    break;
            }
        }
```

It's a pity that all browsers work fine with the exception of Firefox, which is still an
important and widely utilized web browser.
Maybe you have an idea of how to solve this inconvenience?
Thank you for your help.